# Modules and Angular Component is not a known element error

Tags: angular, module, angular-module

I have a module like this:

```
// app.module.ts
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
...
],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    SharedModule,
...
]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And another module like this:

```
// shared.module.ts
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    myComponent,
    myOtherComponent,
...
],
  imports: [
    OtherModule,
...
],
  exports: [
    myComponent,
    myOtherComponent,
...
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

In myComponent template I have something like this:

```
<div>
<my-other-component></my-other-component>
</div>
```

The application works perfectly, but in VSC I see the tag my-other-component like an error,
that says
`'my-other-component' is not a known element:

1. If 'my-other-component' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'my-other-component' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.ngtsc(-998001) `

Usually when I got this error I just need to add MyOtherComponent to AppModule or SharedModule and it got fixed... but not this time.
Why?

Thanks a lot!

I tried to add MyOtherComponent to AppComponent too, but on the browser I get another error that says:
`compiler.js:2175 Uncaught Error: Type MyOtherComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: SharedModule and AppModule!`

Comment: I think this is a problem with your VSC configuration. Can you try to close the project and repoen it? If the problem persist, can you try to recreate the problem with stackblitz.com?

Comment: I closed project and open it again, nothing changed. :(

Comment: but your code works from the command line, and it does not crash while visiting the webpage, only your VSC shows an error?

Comment: Are you using the correct selector? `[my-other-component]` is an attribute, while `my-other-component` is a tag.

Comment: Yes, I use the correct selector and the application works fine! The only problem is about VSC that gives me an error (and only in VSC, I don't get any error from the browser's console).

Comment: Exactly ForestG, my code works and doesn't crash at all, only VSC shows me plenty of errors.

Answer (score 0):

you've exported `myComponent` and `myOtherComponent` from `SharedModule` and imported `SharedModule` again in the same file. remove `SharedModule` from the imports of sharedmodule.ts

Comment: No, SharedModule it's not actually imported in SharedModule. I just messed up making the example. My bad, sorry.

Comment: ok, try adding your declarations after the exports in sharedmodule.ts, since its declared and used before it was exported, VSC or Language service might not pickup on it